# How to scrape multiple tables using scrapy?

Tags: web, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

Hello am trying to scrape through multiple tables from this site https://hs.e-to-china.com and i want to loop through tables and get the needed information.
The problem is it only scrapes the first table and repeats it as many times as there is tables in that page.My question is how can i go from table to the next one.
Here is the code am using:

```
tables = response.xpath('//*[@class="tax-table"]').extract()
for table in tables:
                    hs_code = response.xpath('//*[@class="hs-code"]//code/text()').extract_first()
                    Unit = response.xpath('//*[@class="tax-table"]//tr[1]//td[1]/text()').extract_first()
                    Gen_General_Tariff_Rate = response.xpath('//*[@class="tax-table"]//tr[1]//td[2]/text()').extract_first()
                    MFN_Most_favored_Nation = response.xpath('//*[@class="tax-table"]//tr[1]//td[3]/text()').extract_first()

                    TaxVAT_Value_added_Tax = response.xpath('//*[@class="tax-table"]//tr[2]//td[1]/text()').extract_first()
                    Additional_Tariff_on_US_Imports =  response.xpath('//*[@class="tax-table"]//tr[2]//td[2]/text()').extract_first()
                    Export_Tax_Rebate = response.xpath('//*[@class="tax-table"]//tr[2]//td[3]/text()').extract_first()

                    Regulations_and_Restrictions = response.xpath('//*[@class="tax-table"]//tr[3]//td[1]/text()').extract_first()
                    Inspection_and_Quarantine = response.xpath('//*[@class="tax-table"]//tr[3]//td[2]/text()').extract_first()
                    Consumption_Tax = response.xpath('//*[@class="tax-table"]//tr[3]//td[3]/text()').extract_first()

                    FTA_Free_Trade_Agreement_Tax = response.xpath('//*[@class="tax-table"]//tr[4]//td[1]/text()').extract_first()
                    CCC_Certificate = response.xpath('//*[@class="tax-table"]//tr[4]//td[2]/text()').extract_first()
                    In_Quota_on_Imported_Goods = response.xpath('//*[@class="tax-table"]//tr[4]//td[3]/text()').extract_first()

                    IT_Origin_Country_Tariff = response.xpath('//*[@class="tax-table"]//tr[5]//td[1]/text()').extract_first()
                    Anti_Dumping_Anti_Subsidy = response.xpath('//*[@class="tax-table"]//tr[5]//td[2]/text()').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull when to use een XPath starting with `//`

This tells the engine to start from root.
If you are in a loop start with  `.//` to use the current context

So instead off

```
hs_code = response.xpath('//*[@class="hs-code"]//code/text()').extract_first()
```

Use :

```
hs_code = response.xpath('.//*[@class="hs-code"]//code/text()').extract_first()
```